# Linear LATEST BY performance in QuestDB

Tags: questdb

I observe linear time increase with number of rows in the table when I query `LATEST BY` symbol in QuestDB as if it does full scan to find the values. Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE metric(
   ObjectType SYMBOL capacity 2 cache , 
   ObjectId SYMBOL capacity 20000 cache, 
   Group SYMBOL capacity 4000 cache, 
   Region SYMBOL capacity 20 cache, 
   CC Symbol capacity 50 cache,
   value DOUBLE,
   timestamp TIMESTAMP
) 
timestamp(timestamp)
PARTITION BY DAY;
```

And query is

```
select value from metric 
LATEST BY ObjectType
where objectType= 'queue'
```

I'd expect linear or logarithmic time growth for it.

Answer (score 0):

An index is needed to avoid full table scan and to have linear `LATEST BY` SELECT query performance

Try

```
ALTER table metric ALTER COLUMN objectType ADD INDEX
```

or you should create table

```
CREATE TABLE metric(
   ObjectType SYMBOL capacity 2 cache index, 
   ObjectId SYMBOL capacity 20000 cache, 
   Group SYMBOL capacity 4000 cache, 
   Region SYMBOL capacity 20 cache, 
   CC Symbol capacity 50 cache,
   value DOUBLE,
   timestamp TIMESTAMP
) 
timestamp(timestamp)
PARTITION BY DAY;
```

Symbol by itself is not indexed it just merely means that repeated string values will be saved as integers in a row with a separate lookup table (symbol dictionary) translating from integer to string.